# Output for if/else statement not showing/variable assignment issues; Beginner programmer

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm pretty new to programming, so I'm sort of confused as to why this code isn't working. For example, if I enter `"C"` for vehicle, and `1` for both hours and minutes, it just stops there and doesn't enter `if` block. I know it's missing the `else` portion but just to note I tried it with that but it didn't make a difference. As soon as I enter a value for minutes the program reaches the `Press any key to continue...` state. Help please?

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char vehicle;
    int hours, minutes;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

    cout << "If your vehicle is a car, please enter 'C'" << endl;
    cout << "If your vehicle is a truck, please enter 'T'" << endl;
    cout << "If you are a senior citizen, please enter 'S'" << endl;
    cout << "\nEnter here: ";
    cin >> vehicle;

    cout << "\nEnter the number of hours you have been parked: ";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "\nEnter the number of minutes you have been parked: ";
    cin >> minutes;

    if (vehicle == ('C' || 'c') && minutes <= 30)
    {  
        if (hours <= 2)
        cout << "Free" << endl;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (vehicle == ('C' || 'c') && minutes <= 30)
```

doesn't do what you think it does. You need to use:

```
if ( (vehicle == 'C' || vehicle =='c') && minutes <= 30)
```

You can simplify it to:

```
if ( toupper(vehicle) == 'C' && minutes <= 30)
```

Comment: What input did you give? What happened? What did you expect? Just telling us that something "didn't work" isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a logic error (or you can say syntax-error that led to logic error).

In if condition you should check for vehicle with uppercase and lower case like this:

`if ((vehicle == 'C' || vehicle == 'c') && minutes <= 30)`

You are checking for vehicle to be 'C' or 'c' but unknowingly you are doing bitwise operation on 'C' and 'c'. These are beginner mistakes, but also integral part of learning.

Comment: I changed it to this but it's still not outputting anything

Comment: @cali4niakris What input did you give?

Comment: @cali4niakris please put a cout statement right after if, and check if it prints.

Comment: I input c, 1, 1, and got nothing. within the if statement was another if that was 
`if(hours<=2)
cout << "Free";`
Still got nothing

Comment: @cali4niakris please try this url http://cpp.sh/96rii, there is the full code. I entered following inputs

C for vehicle, 2 for hours and 30 for minutes and it print 'free'.

Comment: @cali4niakris on C, 1, 1 it also prints 'free'.

Comment: I realized I wasn't paying attention and that the "Free" just printed directly next to the "Press any key" so I didn't see it. Thanks for all your help, I feel stupid for not seeing this minor mistake.